# VBA function adding trailing zeros under specific circumstances

Tags: ms-access

I was trying to create a function that would give the value of a number part way through a string.  The various versions I tried weren't working quite as well as planned, and I found a code snippet on http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Find-number-string-Ins-t1746052.html.

The strings that I am trying to pull values from look like:
`A11, A21A23, A25, A23A21, etc.`
There were a few specialized cases where the strings were:
`A23 D0, A23 D1, A23A21 D0, etc.`

For some reason in the instances that included a D, the code would add a zero for whatever quantity followed the D.  So `A23 D0` returns: `23`, as it should `A23 D1`, however, returns `230`.  `A23 D3` returns `23000`, and so on.

I am fairly new to VBA, and I cannot figure out what would cause the letter D to add trailing zeros, where other letters substituted for the D do not have the same effect.

The VBA script is as follows:

```
Public Function GetNumFromStringFloating(strText As String, Optional intPos As Integer = 1) As String
'? GetNumFromStringFloating("12*TLG AUTVTG18871890AAUG")    = 12
'? GetNumFromStringFloating("12*TLG AUTVTG18871890AAUG",3)  = 12
'? GetNumFromStringFloating("12*TLG AUTVTG18871890AAUG",14) = 18871890
'? GetNumFromStringFloating("12*TLG AUTVTG18871890AAUG",-1) = 18871890  (Reverse Search)
Dim X As Integer
If intPos > 0 Then
    For X = intPos To Len(strText)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(strText, X, 1)) Then
            GetNumFromStringFloating = val(Mid(strText, X) & "")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next X
Else
    For X = Len(strText) To Abs(intPos) Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Mid(strText, X, 1)) Then
            GetNumFromStringFloating = val(Mid(strText, X) & "")
        Else
            If GetNumFromStringFloating <> "" Then Exit For
        End If
    Next X
End If
End Function
```

Comment: What is your business rule exactly? What is the input and what is the output you want?

Comment: There is a certain amount of misunderstanding of Val (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/val-function-HA001228931.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may suit:

```
Function getnum(sText)
''A11, A21A23, A25, A23A21
Dim sNum As String

''Skip the first letter
For i = 2 To Len(sText)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(sText, i, 1)) Then
        sNum = sNum & Mid(sText, i, 1)
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next

getnum = sNum
End Function
```